# Find, copy, rename within the same directory

Tags: bash, find, rename, cp

I an new to bash and could do with some help. I am looking to create a command that will instantly duplicate the last created file with a new new. So far I come up with the following command;

```
find /home/ian/Desktop/TEST/ -type f -mmin -1 -exec echo cp {} /home/ian/Desktop/TEST/ \;
```

But for the life or me I cannot find a way to rename the file and I have looked around and tried various methods but none seemed to work. I would like to have control over the renaming so that I can add '_backup' to each file that is copied.

What would be the best way to go about this? Sorry if this is such a basic question

All the best, 
Ian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to use `-execdir` instead of `-exec`:

```
-execdir command ;

-execdir command {} +
       Like -exec, but the specified command is run from the  subdirec‐
       tory  containing  the  matched  file,  which is not normally the
       directory in which you started find.
```

The following command seems to work as expected:

```
find /home/ian/Desktop/TEST/ -type f -mmin -1 -execdir echo cp \{} \{}_backup \;
```

Comment: I do have one more question, if you have a file that is called TEST_MASTER how can you run the above and have the new file called TEST_BACKUP as opposed to TEST_MASTER_BACKUP?

Comment: @IanGrey He! He! _"I do have one more question"_ ask an other question and you will see...

Answer (score 0):

you can make the output of a command a string, like `a=$(my_command)`. (My_command being the find.) Then you can say `mv "$a" "$a".backup`.

Answer (score 0):

```
find /home/ian/Desktop/TEST/ -type f -mmin -1 -exec echo cp {} /home/ian/Desktop/TEST/{}_backup
```