# execdir and rename commands together?

Tags: bash, rename

I ask a question about finding, copying and renaming which can be found here [Find, copy, rename within the same directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24684470/find-copy-rename-within-the-same-directory/24685594?noredirect=1#comment38293467_24685594)

The answer was great and solved the issue I had in that thread but it did bring up another question about how I can rename just part of the file....for example when running this command;

```
find /home/ian/Desktop/TEST/ -type f -mmin -1 -execdir echo cp \{} \{}_backup \;
```

and the file is called TEST_MASTER how can you run the above and have the new file called TEST_BACKUP as opposed to TEST_MASTER_BACKUP?

I can solve this by running a new rename command straight after like below;

```
find /home/ian/Desktop/TEST/ -type f -mmin -1 -execdir cp \{} \{}_backup \; ;
rename __MASTER_backup _backup *MASTER_backup ;
```

but there must be a way to do this in one go?

All the best, 
Ian

Comment: How about other files that doesn't have MASTER on it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `find` command:

```
find /home/ian/Desktop/TEST/ -type f -mmin -1 -execdir bash -c 'cp "$1" "${1%%_*}_BACKUP"' - '{}' \;
```

Answer (score 0):

I came with almost the same answer as *anubhava*:

```
find /home/ian/Desktop/TEST/ -type f -name '*_MASTER' -mmin -1 -execdir \
         bash -c 'mv $1 ${1/MASTER/BACKUP}' - \{} \;
```

This will *only* backup `*_MASTER` files. If you need to backup the other files as well (and add an extra `_BACKUP` at the end, vote for anubhava!